# Autocomplete is not working (browser chrome)

Tags: css, html

I have a form login. Normaly, the chrome save the settings, and each time the user access to that form, the last input values are automatically insert. But in my form, the browser does not behaves like that.

[Edit] : This behavior it is just appending to chrome browser

Follows the HTML code:

```html
<form action="#" class="ac-custom ac-checkbox ac-checkmark" onsubmit="UIAuthetication.prototype.ClickButtonSignedIn(true); return false;">
                            <div class="username line checkThisDiv">
                                <input class="input TR_Login_Username" type="text" required="" placeholder="E-mail" mandatory="" vk_15c42="subscribed">
                                <h6 class="TR_Login_Username">E-mail</h6>
                                <p class="error_message"></p>
                            </div>
                                                    <div class="password line checkThisDiv">
                                <input class="input TR_Login_Password" type="password" required="" placeholder="Password" mandatory="" vk_15c42="subscribed">
                                <h6 class="TR_Login_Password">Password</h6>
                                <p class="error_message"></p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="line line-submit">
                                <input class="submit right TR_Login_Button" type="submit" value="Login">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <input class="keepSignIn remember" type="checkbox">
                                        <label class="TR_Login_Keep_Me_Signed_In" for="cb6">Remember user</label>
                                    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>


                    </form>
```

Comment: Why `autocomplete="on"` on password field? Use cookies for that. I can change input type to `text` and see user password.

Comment: Sorry, I change the HTML for the original one's. The code i was post is one that i made changes for testing if, some how, the property autocomplete="on" fixes the problem.
I don't wanna use cookies because it is not the propose. Like I said, the problem is that the browser doesn't field automatically when should do it.

Comment: Have you confirmed logins to be remembered when pop-up appears? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#The_autocomplete_attribute_and_login_fields

Comment: Yes, I did that. I testes again and for IE and Mozzila is working fine, but for chrome, for some reason, when the pop-up appears, i accept but when i return to login page, the chrome does not autocomplete the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, with the attempt-error method, I discovery if I put ID's to the inputs, the chrome autocomplete will work. I don't know the reason of that, I just know with that, the problem was solve.